# I am adding a Review date of 3 years after the published date. How do I hide the review date until the published date is added

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In and Excel worksheet, I am adding a Review date of three years after the published date. How do I hide the review date until the published date is added?

I have tried `If (H3=",",` then the formula, but get the word `FALSE` appearing in the I3 cell.

Any assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The reason your formula isn't working is that quote marks work in pairs to identify text.  If you want to test for an empty cell, you need two quote marks with nothing between them (a text string of nothing).  In your formula, your test target is the comma.

There are a number of ways to test for an empty cell.  Here's a solution that demonstrates the proper use of your "null" for the result value, and another common test for an empty cell.

*I'm assuming that Publication Date is in Cell A2 then write this formula in C2 which has Review Date.*

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",DATE(YEAR(A2)+3,MONTH(A2),DAY(A2)))
```

**How it works:**

- Formula checks if Cell `A2(Publication Date)` is Blank then Excel will
  not execute the formula & keep the `C2 blank`, otherwise will add `3` to
  year to get *Date after 3 years.*

**N.B.** Adjust cell references in formula as needed.

Comment: @fixer1234, thanks for useful updates,,,, will help OP & others too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
=IF(H3="", "", the_formula)
```

Comment: Scott, this one was in the LQP review queue.  It wouldn't hurt to add a sentence explaining "why".  :-)